# Fluent interfaces with pipelining or method chaining in Python

Tags: python, functional-programming, pipeline, fluent, method-chaining

I am coming to Python from F# and Elixir, and I am struggling heavily in terms of cleanly coding data transformations. Every language I have ever used has had a concept of a pipeline operator and/or method chaining, and so with Python, I am confused on finding an *easy* way to accomplish this that doesn't stray away from so-called "Pythonic" code.

Here's a simple collection of some processing functions I might have:

```py
def convert_int_to_bool(integer: int) -> bool:
    match integer:
        case 0:
            return False
        case 1:
            return True
        case _:
            ValueError(
                f"Integer value must be either 0 or 1 to be converted to `bool`. Given: {integer}"
            )

def convert_string_to_characters(string: str) -> list[str]:
    return [character for character in string]
```

In Python, I can do something like:

```py
def test(response: str) -> <some type>:
    [a, b, c, d] = map(convert_int_to_bool, map(int, convert_string_to_characters(response)))
    ...
```

But this is non-ideal, even in a simple case of mapping over the list twice. Well, then I know I could do something like:

```py
[a, b, c, d] = [convert_int_to_bool(int(character)) for character in response]
```

That's *okay*, but it again doesn't scale all that well to a chain of processing functions, especially if there's a `filter` inside there. So what I'd like to do is *something like*:

```py
[a, b, c, d] = response.convert_string_to_characters().map(int).map(convert_int_to_bool)
```

or

```py
[a, b, c, d] = response |> convert_string_to_characters() |> map(int) |> map(convert_int_to_bool)
```

For the first proposed way with method chaining, it seems I could *potentially* do this by extending the built-in types of `str` and `list`, but then that has issues from I have read about not integrating well with the built-in literal constructions of those types.

---

Are there any libraries or ways of overloading/overriding built-in types or defining custom operators that would allow me to do this in a clean way? Thank you.

Comment: *don't use `map`*. Use a list comprehensions. In any case, Python supports method chaining if the type supports method chaining. If it doesn't, then it doesn't/

Comment: "but it again doesn't scale all that well to a chain of processing functions, especially if there's a filter" sure it does: `[<some mapping operation> for x in whatever if <predicate>]`

Comment: (1) Why not use `map`? (2) Yes, of course, but I'm discussing built-in types. (3) I find those list comprehensions difficult to follow. What if you have multiple filters and maps?

Comment: `map` and `filter` should almost always be replaced with some sort of comprehension construct. What  is the problem with multiple maps and filters? If you need to do a filter in a particular order, then just use an intermediate variable. Python has very different syntax compared to F# and Elixer, you can probably cook something up to approximate it, but I highly suggest you stop fighting against the language and learn to use the idioms provided.

Comment: Again, why? `map` and `filter` are built into the language and don't even need importing. I'm not "fighting" against anything, hence this question of trying to figure things out and experiment in a principled manner. It is Python that has fought, since it was invented over 30 years ago, against existing at that time and continuing concepts and acceptance of such of dataflow processing. I'm comfortable with list comprehensions (F# and Elixir have them too), but I find it disappointing if that's the answer to everything.

Comment: Generally, you use the "identity" (in quotes, because I'm not going to dive into possible implementation details that separate Python from category theory) `map(f, map(g, ...)) == map(lambda x: f(g(x)), ...)` and compose the two functions yourself.

Comment: If you are interested, there is a Python superset called [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org) that compiles to Python and *does* implement `|>` (along with a host of other ideas from functional languages.)

Answer (score -1):

> Are there any libraries or ways of overloading/overriding built-in
> types or defining custom operators that would allow me to do this in a
> clean way?

I suggest taking look at popular external package [`pandas`](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/) or more precisely `pandas.Series.apply`. Simple example of applying 3 functions to Series of integers in succession.

```
import pandas as pd
def square(x):
    return x ** 2
def evenify(x):
    return 2 * (x // 2)
def add_one(x):
    return x + 1
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
s2 = s.apply(square).apply(evenify).apply(add_one)
print(s2)
```

gives output

```
0     1
1     5
2     9
3    17
4    25
5    37
6    49
7    65
8    81
dtype: int64
```

You might use Series just like list in many respects (e.g. to retrieve 1st element from changed do `s2[0]`).

> seems I could potentially do this by extending the built-in types of
> `str` and `list`, but then that has issues from I have read about not
> integrating well with the built-in literal constructions of those
> types.

If you want to avoid external dependency, but want list-like which allow chaining I suggest making use of [`collections.UserList`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserList) e.g. by doing

```
import collections
class MyList(collections.UserList):
    def map(self, func):
        return MyList(map(func, self.data))
lst = MyList([1,2,3,4,5])
lst.map(square).map(evenify).map(add_one)
```

Comment: `pd.Series` saren't really a good replacement for a `list`

Comment: Furthermore, this is *absolutey the wrong way to use `pd.Series` in this case*. You shouldn't be using `apply` here at all, and you shouldn't use it ever if you can avoid using it. Use the vectorized operations!